# Is $\vec{0}\in\left<\emptyset\right>$ the only zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is $\vec{0}\in\left<\emptyset\right>$ the only zero vector?

It seem as though it has to be.  The zero vector is the sum of vectors multiplied by the scalar $0$.  And the product of $0$ with any vector is the zero vector.  Furthermore, the zero vector has no components since $\vec{0}\in\left<\emptyset\right>$ has no components, and adding the zero vector to a vector is an identity operation.

In terms of analytic geometry, the zero vector is the single structureless point called the origin.

Is this correct?

Comment: In the first line, you forgot the angled brackets.

Comment: You were doing fine until you came to nonsense like " the zero vector is the single structureless point called the origin".

Comment: @GEdgar that part isn't in doubt.  It is the historically accepted characterization of the Euclidian point combined with the standard concept of rectangular Cartesian coordinates, introduced by Rene Descartes as the foundation of his analytic geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\vec{z}$ were a different zero vector.  Then 
$$  \vec{0} = \vec{0} + \vec{z} = \vec{z}  \text{.}  $$
That is, $\vec{z}$ is actually the usual zero vector.

Comment: So, do you agree that there is only one zero vector in the Universe, at least when we use the same field of scalar s?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton : No.  The vectors in one vector space are not automatically vectors in another vector space.  Perhaps the easiest way to see this is that the vector space of polynomials of degree up to $2$ contains polynomials, but the vector space of positions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains points.  But both of these vector spaces are 3-dimensional real vector spaces.  (Don't conflate the lists of coordinates relative to some basis with the objects actually in the space.  The list of three "$0$" coordinates is neither a polynomial nor a point.)

Comment: How many empty sets are there?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton : Exactly one.  None of them are a vector space.

Comment: But the span of the empty set is a vector space.  I haven't given the matter close scrutiny, but I expect the zero vector of the vector space of polynomials is good old fashioned $0$, which is also the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^1$, etc.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton : The zero vector of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ is a point, not a polynomial.  The zero vector of a vector space of polynomials is a polynomial, not a point.  Recall that a vector space is a set with elements satisfying certain properties.  Those elements have whatever types they have -- having a vector space structure doesn't delete all other structure.

Comment: A point in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is also called a real number.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton : Yet even more structure that polynomials don't have.  Are you trying to prove my point?

Comment: I'm getting overflow warnings so this will be my last comment.  The zero polynomial over a field of scalars is the constant function mapping every scalar to zero.  That is multiplication by zero.  So I don't see how to distinguish the zero polynomial from the zero scalar.  Since I am most interested in physics, I will continue to use distinct notation for the number $0$ and the zero vector, but I believe they are exactly the same thing.  Infact, I use juxtaposition to indicate the tensor, or dyadic product, so the zero vector acts just like the number zero in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

For any vector space $V$ there is exactly one zero vector $0_V\in V$, which may be described as the identity of the group $(V,+)$.

Given a vector space $V$, it is true that $\{0_V\}=\langle \emptyset\rangle$ (and I presume you mean $\langle S\rangle=\operatorname{span}S$ ), because $\{0_V\}$ is in fact the intersection of all the linear subspaces $U\subseteq V$ such that $\emptyset\subseteq U$.

Comment: I corrected the post.  It is challenging to use a phone to post mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Every vector space has exactly one $0$ vector. I don't know what $\langle \emptyset \rangle$ is, but it is not really correct to say that $0\in V$ is equal to $0\in W$ if $V\neq W$ as sets. More concretely, $0\in \Bbb R$ is not equal to $(0,0)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Probably $\langle\cdot\rangle$ ere refers to the linear hull, that is,$\langle S\rangle = \{\sum_{v\in S}c_v v | c_v \in F\}$ where $F$ is the field of scalars referring to the vector space (given that the OP used the $\vec v$ notation, probably $F=\mathbb R$). In particular, $\langle\emptyset\rangle=\{0\}$ because the empty sum is the zero vector.

Comment: $\left\{\vec{0}\right\}=\left<\emptyset\right>$ is the zero dimensional span of the empty set, and has the zero vector as its sole element.  See Evar Nering, Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory, 2nd Ed. Page 15.